# Onclick mutiple switch button not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Here I want to add multiple switch buttons on the same page. I had added but `querySelector` is not working. Can anyone guide me on what might be the reason the switch is not working.

```js
allOnOffButtons = document.querySelectorAll("div.case-inner-info input");

allOnOffButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', handleVisibility);
})

function handleVisibility(e) {
  // check if the button was on or off
  const clickedButtonId = e.srcElement.id;
  const clickedinnerDiv = e.srcElement.closest(".case-inner-info").querySelector(".inner_div");
  // find all divs inside the given inner_div
  const allDivsInsideInnerDiv = clickedinnerDiv.querySelectorAll("div");
  // check if they should be shown or hidden
  allDivsInsideInnerDiv.forEach(div => {
    if (div.id === clickedButtonId) {
      div.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="case-inner-info">
  <div class="case-switch-wrap">
    <div class="inner_div">
      <div class="case-info" id="on">
        <p> Paragrapgh1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="case-code-wrap" style="display: none;" id="off">
        <p> Paragrapgh2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="case-switch">
      <input type="radio" class="switch-input" id="on" checked>
      <label for="on" class="switch-label switch-label-on">On</label>
      <input type="radio" class="switch-input" id="off">
      <label for="off" class="switch-label switch-label-off">Off</label>
      <span class="switch-selection"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="case-inner-info">
  <div class="case-switch-wrap">
    <div class="inner_div">
      <div class="case-info" id="on1">
        <p> Paragrapgh1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="case-code-wrap" style="display: none;" id="off1">
        <p> Paragrapgh2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="case-switch">
      <input type="radio" class="switch-input" id="on1" checked>
      <label for="on1" class="switch-label switch-label-on">On</label>
      <input type="radio" class="switch-input" id="off1">
      <label for="off1" class="switch-label switch-label-off">Off</label>
      <span class="switch-selection"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: `e.srcElement` should be `e.target` -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/srcElement

Comment: Your HTML is invalid with duplicate id properties on multiple elements https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: You also have multiple id attributes with the same value, this is invalid code, ID's must be unique, use dataset attributes for those.  `data-id='on'`

Comment: You're including jQuery, tagged your question with it, but you're not using it?

Comment: @j08691 Yeah previously i trying to do with jquery but I unable to achieve it.

Comment: you are wrong about the use of radio buttons, they work in groups with the same group name, and can have different values each, they are not true / false logic  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/radio

Comment: Place your code in https://validator.w3.org/ and see where all it fails to validate rather than us all trying to do so manually since it will not work with your code until it is valid.

Comment: You still haven't said exactly what behavior you're looking for here. It's hard for us to help when we don't know what the expected result should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery import wasn't needed, so I removed it. You can easily get the relative paths to switch your display using data-attributes (I used `data-ref`) instead of IDs with:

```
e.target.closest('.case-inner-info')
  .querySelectorAll('.inner_div [data-ref]')
  .forEach(i => i.style.display = i.dataset.ref === e.target.dataset.ref ? 'block' : 'none');
```

```js
const handleVisibility = (e) => {
  e.target.closest('.case-inner-info').querySelectorAll('.inner_div [data-ref]').forEach(i => i.style.display = i.dataset.ref === e.target.dataset.ref ? 'block' : 'none');
}
const allOnOffButtons = document.querySelectorAll("div.case-inner-info input");
allOnOffButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', handleVisibility);
})
```

```html
<div class="case-inner-info">
  <div class="case-switch-wrap">
    <div class="inner_div">
      <div class="case-info" data-ref="on">
        <p> Paragrapgh1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="case-code-wrap" style="display: none;" data-ref="off">
        <p> Paragrapgh2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="case-switch">
      <label class="switch-label switch-label-on">
      <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="switch-toggle" data-ref="on" checked>
      On</label>
      <label class="switch-label switch-label-off">
      <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="switch-toggle" data-ref="off">
      Off</label>
      <span class="switch-selection"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="case-inner-info">
  <div class="case-switch-wrap">
    <div class="inner_div">
      <div class="case-info" data-ref="on">
        <p> Paragrapgh1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="case-code-wrap" style="display: none;" data-ref="off">
        <p> Paragrapgh2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="case-switch">
      <label class="switch-label switch-label-on">
      <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="switch-toggle" data-ref="on" checked>
      On</label>
      <label class="switch-label switch-label-off">
      <input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="switch-toggle" data-ref="off">
      Off</label>
      <span class="switch-selection"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @husna you were also using the same ID on different DOM elements.

Comment: @Kinglish This is what exactly I'm trying to achieve.